# How to fix "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" in PHP/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress theme is loading fonts. On Archive pages only this causes an error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

If I reload the page I see this in inspect/console:

GET http://michaelalexis.commichaelalexis.com/?family=Open+Sans%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C600%2C600italic%7CDroid+Sans%3A400%2C700&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

It appears that the archive pages are pulling an incorrect value for the site URL, which should be https://michaelalexis.com. The archive pages worked correctly in the past, and all other pages on the site seem to load correctly. I found areas of the theme that reference these fonts, but not the GET call. How do I resolve this or what should I be looking for?

Example of broken archive: https://michaelalexis.com/personal-finance/

Thank you.

I've looked through many/all of what seem to be the relevant theme files. I also queried the database for "michaelalexis.commichaelalexis.com" to see if it would come up, but nothing.

https://michaelalexis.com/personal-finance/

Success = the page loads correctly.

Comment: Try re-saving Permalinks in settings.

Comment: Thanks, didn't work.